# Scrapy: How to exclude redirect 404

Tags: scrapy

I'm scraping a particular URL set: e.g.

```
example.com/job/1
example.com/job/3
example.com/job/4
example.com/job/31
example.com/job/50
```

The problem is, I don't know which ones have been removed, and if I decide to crawl from 1 to 10000, I will get a lot of redirects to page not found e.g.

```
example.com/job-not-found.html
```

I used the while loop to define the starting URLs, but now I want Scrapy to exclude from the parse method all URL's that get redirected to the 404 page.

Currently I get a lot of unnecessary h1 tags belonging to the 404 page because they still parse.

Answer (score 0):

`Scrapy` ignores 404 responses by default, which means you have disabled it somehow, check for the following attributes in `settings`, your spider code or maybe passing it throught the `meta` parameters:

- `handle_httpstatus_list`
- `handle_httpstatus_all`
- `HTTPERROR_ALLOWED_CODES`
- `HTTPERROR_ALLOW_ALL`

Any of those variables should be True or should be a list containing the `404` status.

If that isn't your case, probably you've disabled the `HttpErrorMiddleware` middleware.